# Consumir un Web Service Json con PHP

Tags: php, json, webservice

Buenos días como están, espero que muy bien, me gustaría que me ayudarán un poco en un asunto de consumir un web service a través de una URL que deberia devolver un resultado en JSON, cosa que no funciona y además en el resultado solo me arroja símbolos raros, este asunto me esta complicando un poco.

A continuación muestro la forma como la estoy haciendo, desde ya muchas gracias.

$apiUrl = 'http://api.cne.cl/v3/combustibles/calefaccion/estaciones?token=PT33JekNhp&distribuidor=Copec';

```
if(ini_get('allow_url_fopen')){
    $json = file_get_contents($apiUrl);
} else{
    $curl = curl_init($apiUrl);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $json = curl_exec($curl);
    print($json);
    curl_close($curl);
}
```

Comment: ¿Símbolos raros? Creo que necesitas decodificar el JSON: `print(json_decode($json));`. Verifica también que tienes la codificación `UTF-8` bien configurada en tu entorno.

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta, pero no ha surtido efecto.

Comment: ¿Qué te imprime, símbolos extraños como el carácter inspector?

Comment: No muestra la respuesta que debe y muestra esto (http://disennosweb.com/Proy_Inmo/4/muestra.PNG)

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que limpiar los datos, con `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING ,"");`.

Según el [Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.curl-setopt.php):

> Contenido del valor "Accept-Encoding: " en el header. **Esto permite
>   decodificar la respuesta**. Los formatos de codificación disponibles
>   son "identity", "deflate", y "gzip". Si el valor se envía vacío, "",
>   se enviarán todos los tipos de condificación soportados.

Hice una prueba con este código:

```
$apiUrl = 'http://api.cne.cl/v3/combustibles/calefaccion/estaciones?token=PT33JekNhp&distribuidor=Copec';
$curl = curl_init($apiUrl);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING ,"");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$json = curl_exec($curl);
print($json);
curl_close($curl);
```

Y me presenta los datos bien:

```
{
    "estado": "OK",
    "descripcion": "Token Valida",
    "data": [{
                "id": "co110101",
                "fecha_hora_actualizacion": "2018-02-01 09:57:15",
                "razon_social": "BORRADO POR CONFIDENCIALIDAD",
                "direccion_calle": "BORRADO",
                "direccion_numero": "BORRADO",
                "id_comuna": "01101",
                "nombre_comuna": "Iquique",
                "id_region": "01",
                "nombre_region": "Tarapac\u00e1",
                "horario_atencion": "24 horas",
 .....
```